# Clear way to update some nested struct from a bigger struct in place

Tags: swift

Say we have some complex struct with multiple nested levels(for simplicity, in the example will be only one level, but there could be more).

Example. We have a data structure:

```
struct Company {
    var employee: [Int: Employee]
}

struct Employee {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

var company = Company(employee: [
    1: Employee(name: "Makr", age: 25),
    2: Employee(name: "Lysa", age: 30),
    3: Employee(name: "John", age: 28)
    ])
```

Now we want to create a function which updates some Employee of the company in place. We could write it using an `inout` param:

```
func setAge(_ age: Int, forEmployee employee: inout Employee) {
    employee.age = age  
}

setAge(26, forEmployee: &company.employees[1]!)
```

This works, but as you can see we need to unwrap expression 'company.employees[1]' before passing it by ref. This forced unwrap can produce runtime error if there is no such employee for the provided key.

So we need to check if the employee exists:

```
if company.employees[1] != nil {
    setAge(26, forEmployee: &company.employees[1]!)
}
```

This also works, but this code is kind of ugly because we need to repeat the expression 'company.employees[1]' two times.

So the question is: Is there some way to get rid of this repetition?

I tried to use optional inout param in the modifying function but could not get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, like

> What I wanted in the first place is just to have a reference to a substructure of a bigger structure so the part of code that is dealing with the substructure could know nothing about where is this substructure located in the bigger structure.

and

> It would be ideal if I just could create a local inout var. Like if var employ: inout Employee? = company.employee[1] { // make whatever I want with that employee }.

I think that what you want is a generic update function. In the community this is part of the family of utility functions referred as `with` (https://forums.swift.org/t/circling-back-to-with/2766)

The version that you need in this case is one that basically `guard`s on `nil`, so I suggest something like

```swift
func performUpdateIfSome <T> (_ value: inout T?, update: (inout T) throws -> Void) rethrows {
  guard var _value = value else { return }
  try update(&_value)
  value = _value
}
```

with this utility then what you wanted to do would be done with

```swift
performUpdateIfSome(&company.employees[1], update: { $0.age = 26 })
```

#### Note

If you want to abstract away *how to access the employee* but not the `company`, then keypaths are an option as well :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. There though two misspellings in your function. There should be 'var' in the guard statement and the _value should be passed to the update function by ref like this update(&_value)

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the implementation and let the struct handle the logic with specific error handling strategy, like throwing an error or simply return true/false depending on success or simply ignore any problems. I don't know what the Int key stands for but here I guess it's an ID of some sort, so add this to Company struct

```
mutating func setAge(_ age: Int, forId id: Int) -> Bool {
    if employee.keys.contains(id) {
        employee[id]?.age = age
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but a way to go. Thanks!

Comment: You can condense the function body to `return (employee[id]?.age = age) != nil` :)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add extension to `Employee` which set employee's `age`

```
extension Employee {
    mutating func setAge(_ age: Int) {
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

Then you can use optional chaining for calling. So if value for key `1` doesn't exist, nothing happens and code goes on

```
company.employee[1]?.setAge(26)
```

---

Edit:

If your goal is just to change some property and then return object, simply create method which takes optional parameter and returns optional value

```
func setAge(_ age: Int, forEmployee employee: inout Employee?) -> Employee? {
    employee?.age = age
    return employee
}

if let employee = setAge(26, forEmployee: &company.employees[1]) { ... }
```

Comment: Why would you need a setAge function instead of doing employee.age = age?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Why would he need his initial method at all?

Comment: Maybe the example is misleading because it is too simple. What I wanted in the first place is just to have a reference to a substructure of a bigger structure so the part of code that is dealing with the substructure could know nothing about where is this substructure located in the bigger structure.

Comment: It would be ideal if I just could create a local inout var. Like  if  var employ: inout Employee? = company.employee[1] { // make whatever I want with that employee }. But inout can be used only with function params

Comment: @DmitryKlochkov for this you dont need inout reference... but you can just create method which returns value

Comment: Yes, maybe it is just better and simpler to reassign the updated employee value back to where it was retrieved

Comment: "Why would he need his initial method at all?" To both find the right object _and_ change the property.